# Roles, authorization and permissions in asp.net mvc 5.2.7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, permissions

What is the standard way of issuing permissions and roles in asp.net mvc? I have creating accounts, saving them and logging in down but have no idea where I create my rules and specify their permissions. I found this online;

```
  <roleManager enabled="true"
            defaultProvider="SecurityTutorialsSqlRoleProvider"
            cacheRolesInCookie="true"
            createPersistentCookie="false"
            cookieProtection="All">

    <providers>


    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

But, I got this from a page about asp.net core and the usage of this doesn't seem to work in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify roles with Authorize attribute to issue permission for resources like below:

[Authorize(Role = “Admin,Manager”)]

public class AuthController {

}

check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Yes, I found this source, but how do I create the role of admin? and the role of manager? Where do I define these? Are they just the names of models?

Comment: they can be hardcoded if they rarely change . if you are storing externally and bringing into the application you can override the Authorize Atrribute and make your custom Authorize Attribute. While overriding you check if the role has access to a resource .